# link to file in OS in python for QTableWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to create a hyperlink of (file_path ) using python that will point to the file in operating system. I am able to get the path of the file. How can I create a hyperlink of this path and store in a variable. I want to display this in the QtWidgets as link where user can click and open the file stored in windows OS.

```
             file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, FileName)
             self.documents.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(file_path))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QLabel` with html content to create clickable link.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    path = os.environ["USERPROFILE"]
    text = "click me"
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(path, text))
    label.show()
    label.linkActivated.connect(os.startfile)
    app.exec()
```